# How to get the years 1990 to 2022 and possibly into the future?

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I want to create a select and select box from 1990 to present. But it returns an error like: Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react_datepicker__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.range) is not a function

Mycode:

```js
const years = range(1990, getYear(new Date()) + 1, 1);
```

[image: What i need]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means, compiler is unable to find a `range` function.
Most likely in the the example it's referring to [lodash range](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#range) function. You can [import it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.range) OR can create one yourself -

```js
function range (start, end) {
  return new Array(end - start).fill().map((d, i) => i + start);
}

console.log(range(5,10));
```